# Block concurrent threads only when Windows was closed

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have code

```
private void AbrirConexao(string strConexao)
{
    try
    {
        conexao = new NpgsqlConnection(strConexao);
        conexao.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ReconectarDB(null, strConexao);
    }
}

public bool ReconectarDB(string strConexao)
{
    bool erroConexao = false;
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (obj, ea) =>
    {
        int erro = 0;
        while (erro <= 4)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            try
            {
                conexao = new NpgsqlConnection(strConexao);
                conexao.Open();
                erroConexao = false;
                break;
            }
            catch
            {
                erro++;
                erroConexao = true;
            }
        }
    };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (obj, ea) =>
    {
        if (erroConexao)
            DialogReconectando.AlterarTela(ErroConexao.SemConexao);
        else
            DialogReconectando.Close();
    };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (DialogReconectando == null || Conexao.DialogReconectando.IsLoaded == false)
            DialogReconectando = new   DialogErroConexao(ErroConexao.Reconectando);

        if(DialogReconectando.ShowActivated)
        {
            DialogReconectando.ShowActivated = true;
            DialogReconectando.ShowDialog();
        }
    }));

    return erroConexao;
}
```

I am using the Open Connection method to connect to the database. and when the connection fails, ReconnectDB is trying to reconnect with the database. If it fails, a Window is opened that there are two buttons, Retry and Abort the System.

The problem is that there are situations that I use other concurrent threads that makes requests with the database. In those cases, I would not want it to display a new Window. So if there is a Window open, I would like the Thread to lock until the Window is closed. I tried to solve the problem using EventWaitHandle. However, Window is also caught in this situation. Would you have any idea how you could solve this problem?

Comment: not strictly related, but why do you want to keep the connection open? The suggested way to us DBConnection is to open it when needed, execute your query and close it. From a performance point of view, note that by default connections are pooled, so Open actually mean (more or less) "get an open connection from the connection pool" and Close "release the connection to the connection pool, it will be available for the next open request"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want the second thread to do. If you want the second thread to simply skip over showing the window, you can use a [semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure that only a single thread shows the window, like this:

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

private void ShowWindowNonBlocking()
{
    bool acquiredLock = false;
    try
    {
        acquiredLock = semaphore.Wait(0);
        if (acquiredLock)
        {
            // This thread now has exclusive access to the isWindowShown variable
            var result = MessageBox.Show(
                "Retry the connection?",
                "Connection Failed",
                MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);

            if (result == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                // Retry the connection
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Another thread is showing the window
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (acquiredLock)
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a good site that I refer back to from time to time on locking mechanisms: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Semaphore

If however, you want the second thread to block until the first window is finished (for example, if you want to know what the result of the window was in order to know whether to retry on the second thread), you can use a lock, like this:

```
private object windowLock = new object();

private void ShowWindowBlocking()
{
    lock (windowLock)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show(
            "Retry the connection?",
            "Connection Failed",
            MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);

        if (result == DialogResult.Retry)
        {
            // Retry the connection
        }
    }
}
```

If you need further clarification, let me know and I will try to expand the answer.